# How to give regular expression for Regex.ismatch function?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression for accepting a Number of length upto 14 and if they keep the decimal point then it should accept only 2 numbers after the decimal point.

I have tried it from this link below :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9967694/861995

But, the same Regex.IsMatch function is not accepting the normal regex expression's starting with ^ and ending with $.

Please help me on this i am new to regular expressions

```
private void ChangedSellUp_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {            
        string pattern = "^[0-9]*$";            
        Regex rx = new Regex(pattern);
        if (rx.IsMatch(ChangedSellUp.Text))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Here ChangedSellup.Text is my text box value, i am trying to restrict the value based on 2 conditions

1. Its Should Accept only Numbers and length should not increase 14 till Decimal Point.
2. If decimal Point is there after that only 2 numbers are allowed.

e.g ; valid Values -  14.23, 12345678901234.23
      Invalid values - 1.2344, 12345678901234.3455

Please help me with the regex ??

Comment: Please show your exact code that is causing a problem, not a link to another answer. Also, tell us what error is occurring? How do you know it isn't working properly? Maybe it's your regex that is bad

Comment: Your regex will match any sequence of digits, however long, and no other characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the Regex.IsMatch that does what you want:

```
Regex.IsMatch("12345678901234.12", @"^\d{1,14}(?:\.\d{1,2}){0,1}$")
```

That particular regex is for a number up to 14 digits before the decimal point and 1 or 2 digits after the decimal point (with the whole decimal part being optional)

A good place to test it is here: http://regexhero.net/tester/

Because you've mentioned ^ and $, I've included them in the regex, which will only parse lines with just the number (so, for example " 1234.12 " won't return true in the IsMatch, just remove the "^" and "$" if that is not important).

Another good resource for regex is this: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

**UPDATE:**

Since the goal is that the user cannot write anything other than something that satisfies that Regex in a textbox you can do this in the text changed event (key down is not a good option since you'd have to deal with converting KeyEventArg's Key to a char). So the easiest way to achieve what you need is:

```
  private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
  {
     if (!Regex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text, @"^\d{1,14}(?:\.\d{0,2}){0,1}$"))
     {
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, TextBox1.Text.Length - e.Changes.Last().AddedLength);
        TextBox1.CaretIndex = TextBox1.Text.Length;
     }
  }
```

Please notice the slight change in the regular expression that will accept a number followed by a dot, with no extra digits, this is because as you are writing a number with decimal places you'll be in a state where this happens, for example: "123."

Comment: i have done as suggested but my text box is accepting even characters.

Comment: what exactly do you mean when you say that your textbox accepts even characters? Is your goal that your users can only type numbers?

Comment: yes, user should be able to type only numbers with the above mentioned condition, i know the regular expression is correct but the regex.ismatch functiopn is not working

Comment: The regex is the correct(ish) one. I've updated the answer so that it reflects what you need to achieve

Comment: What's the point of that non-capturing-group? That expression is the same as @"^\d{1,14}(\.\d{2})?$" A lot easier to my eyes.

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel If it's easier on your eyes go with it. The reasoning for the non capturing group was the group didn't need to be captured, seemed like a waste to capture it at the time

Answer (score 1):

The best way to build regular expressions is with a Regex Tester. There's a really good one you can download called Cappucino, or you can use a web one, I favour http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Then it is simply a case of building the regex, I'm testing against `12345678901234.00`

If you start with `\d` which is the regex pattern for a numeric digit then you get all sixteen matches you would expect.

Add a `+` which is short for *one or more*, so `\d+` matches twice `12345678901234` and `00`

If you limit to a range of only two digits i.e. `\d{2}` then you get 8 pairs of numbers

To add a `.` you need to escape the character as `.` is a pattern to match any digit, so instead use `\.\d{2}` to match only `.00` (which was your optional part of the number)

If you pattern match a range of digits between 1 and 14 long `\d{1,14}` then you will match `12345678901234` (which is the main number) and `00`

So now you can put it together, we make the post decimal point part optional by saying we want it either 0 or 1 times `{0,1}` or with a shorthand variant `?` to give

`\d{1,14}(\.\d{2})?`

which matches correctly on these

```
12345678901234.00
123456.00
1
1234
```

and because I'm not matching the start and end of the line, also matches on these

```
500.00USD
$1000
```