# Modify text box without moving cursor

Tags: c#, winforms

I've written a check to restrict the user to entering a weight field to no more than one decimal place in a text box.

```
private void txtWeight_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal enteredWeight;
    if (Decimal.TryParse(txtWeight.Text, out enteredWeight))
    {
        decimal roundedWeight = RoundDown(enteredWeight, 1);
        if (enteredWeight != roundedWeight)
        {
            txtWeight.Text = RoundDown(enteredWeight, 1).ToString("F1");
        }
    }
}
```

(the implementation of `RoundDown()` is inconsequential)

My problem is that after the user enters a second digit after the decimal point, it removes it fine, but the cursor is moved to the start of the field.

e.g.

before: `69.2|`

Then type a 4 (e.g. for `69.24` which is not allowed)

after: `|69.2`

I'd like the cursor in the text box to remain wherever it was... Can this be done?

Comment: Probably you mean "caret" when you say "cursor"?

Comment: @UweKeim OK... But I've never heard that term other than the `^` symbol... What's the difference? I'm referring to the blinking line that indicates where the next character will go

Comment: To me "cursor" means "mouse cursor". And "caret" means "text cursor". [Wikipedia has more info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(user_interface)).

Comment: According to your link, both words are correct!

Comment: I know ;-) I just asked to be sure your question relates to the text cursor (aka "caret"), not the mouse cursor.

Comment: maybe this could help   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967558/only-allow-two-digits-after-decimal-in-textbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may save the position of the caret and then re-set it after you have made the text change.

```
private void txtWeight_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal enteredWeight;
    if (Decimal.TryParse(txtWeight.Text, out enteredWeight))
    {
        decimal roundedWeight = RoundDown(enteredWeight, 1);
        if (enteredWeight != roundedWeight)
        {
            int caretPos = txtWeight.SelectionStart;
            txtWeight.Text = RoundDown(enteredWeight, 1).ToString("F1");
            txtWeight.SelectionStart = caretPos;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
txtWeight.Select(txtWeight.Text.Length - 1,0)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
txtWeight.CaretIndex = txtBox.Text.Length;
```

Or:

```
txtWeight.SelectionStart = txtBox.Text.Length;
```

Comment: Isn't this a WPF-only property?

Comment: @UweKeim https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.caretindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why I asked. The user tagged his questions as `winforms`, _not_ as `wpf`.

Comment: But it will put the caret always at the end of the field, regardless of where it was before...